# como puedo pasar un arreglo a string

Tags: php

tengo una duda de como pasar un arreglo a string ya que posteriormente lo utilizare 
mi arreglo es

> $arreglo[$c1];
>   tiene N cantidad de datos

lo que quiero es guardarlo en una variable para posteriormente utilizarla

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tenes este array:

```
  $arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
```

Usando implode lo podes pasar a string, en este caso arma un solo string con los datos del array separados por un vacio:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    $arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
    $datos =  implode(" ",$arr);
    echo $datos;
?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Resultado:

Hello World! Beautiful Day!